# PHP: работа с $argv

Tags: php

```
<?php
$currency = $argv[1];
$pars = simplexml_load_file("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp");
$value=$pars->Valute[$currency]->Value;
?>
```

Скрипт запускаю через консоль, $currency - значение, передаваемое при запуске (числовое)

$pars - парсинг xml страницы

$value в итоге пустая + Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /perl/includes/kurs.php on line 4

В чём проблема?

Спасибо

Comment: `$currency = $argv[1]; var_dump($argv, $currency);`

Что выводит?

Comment: array(2) {

  [0]=>

  string(10) "./kurs.php"

  [1]=>

  string(1) "5"

}

string(1) "5"

Comment: Хотя дело даже не в этом, скорее всего. Проверьте, что содержит `$pars`.

Comment: $value=$pars->Valute[5]->Value;
Тут всё прекрасно работает

Comment: Не верю своим глазам! Спасибо вам, добрый Человек! Всё заработало!

Comment: Переделал в ответ) Вообще я с таким не сталкивался, но в принципе поведение логично. Пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень странно. А если так?

```
$currency = (int) $argv[1];
```